# What makes mobile template different from web template?

Tags: android, ios, html, windows-mobile

Actually I am new to mobile development world, I am going to make a simple HTML5 template for my mobile app. Now I want to know that what is the major differences between web and mobile, suppose. What should be the width? How can a template looks same in a tab and same in a mobile? How to detect that the apps which is accessing url is mobile browser, not windows browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats what make differents about mobile and web

in mobile development you should consider different resolutions for designing
your template for its liquidity to fit on the mobile phone screen

in web its eaasily to design fix template for its resolution is much higher and 
have standard in any browser.. but in functionalities both are the same..